# Canvas Routing Error (uninitialized constant Lti::Ims::NamesAndRolesController::Concerns)

Tags: canvas, lti

I am new on canvas. I am accessing canvas API to get details. I have to connect LTI 1.3 library with canvas. 
I have successfully generated the access_token through this endpoint `login/oauth2/token`. But unable to get member details on this endpoint `/api/lti/courses/2/names_and_roles`.

Yes, I am passing the access token in Authorization. 
Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Kindly suggest me the solution. Is there missing any setting or anything else?  
Thank you!

Comment: I have found a solution to fix this. Go this page location: app/controllers/lti/ims/names_and_roles_controller.rb and change this line.


'include Concerns::AdvantagesServicese'

with this 

'include Lti::Ims::Concerns::AdvantagesServicese'